# Superglobals as parameters in php functions

Tags: php, function, oop, superglobals

I found myself in a need to set a default value for some method parameter from superglobal like:

```
public function some_function ($foo = $_POST['foo'], $bar = $_POST['bar']){
    //some action
}
```

This throws me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE) in /script.php on line (the number of line matches method definition)

If it do like:

```
public function some_function ($foo = "{$_POST['foo']}", $bar = "{$_POST['bar']}")
```

The parser throws:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'
```

Is there a way to set default method parameter values from PHP superglobals?

Comment: You would probably have to do something like default to null and do the assignment in the method if the value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter defaults have to be constant expressions, so you can do something like this:

```
public function some_function ($foo = null, $bar = null)
{
    if ($foo === null) {
        $foo = $_POST['foo'];
    }
    if ($bar === null) {
        $bar = $_POST['bar'];
    }
}
```

If you want to get fancy, you can make sure your defaults have defaults:

```
public function some_function ($foo = null, $bar = null)
{
    if ($foo === null) {
        $foo = $_POST['foo'] ?? 'default foo';
    }
    if ($bar === null) {
        $bar = $_POST['bar'] ?? 'default bar';
    }
}
```

Comment: the 2nd (fancy) one should state that it is PHP 7 exclusive ;-) the OP/others may not know about this type of ternary syntax.